# Order of Parameters to a function

Tags: c++, function, parameters, c++14

Suppose I have a function in C++ which is taking multiple parameters so what should be the order of parameters.

e.g.

```
class Date
{
//heavy class
};

func(int, std::string, Date, ...)
```

Just curious is there any convention to pass parameters depending upon `datatype`.

I got this link in stackoverflow, but still want to check if there any more info on this - 
  [Conventions for order of parameters in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796557/conventions-for-order-of-parameters-in-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't.

Note that C++ doesn't even specify the order in which function parameters are evaluated and passed to the function, although the evaluation of arguments is *sequenced*. So writing something like `func(cheap_function_that_might_throw_an_exception(), expensive_function())` may not necessarily be an optimisation.

Your best bet is to be *consistent* in your application.